# How to load a page with a System Message

Tags: javascript, weblinks

How can I load a page with a system message?

Specifically I have a link and I would like that when a user clicks on the link it opens a specific page with a system message I pass it.

I can see system messages just fine on my site, my template has

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
```

I just don't know what the right code would be to do this. Perhaps the link should actually be a button with an onclick event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Brian's answer (thanks very much @Brian Bolli) and this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323010/execute-php-function-with-onclick - I figured out how to make the link load a page with the message at the top.

The link's code looks like this:

```
<a href="index.php/animals?multiple=true" title="Add multiple animals to mob"><i class="icon-plus "></i>Add multiple animals</a>
```

It is passing a variable to the page I want to load in the url called multiple and it is set to true.

In the page template that loads, the code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['multiple'])) :
    $msg = 'Very helpful message';
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($msg, 'message'); 
endif;
```

It is checking to see if the variable has been set and then if so, it will display the message I want.

Answer (score 5):

You can inject system messages at any point in the page render cycle like so:

JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('My glorious message','error');

The jdoc tag basically creates the place host and loads needed files required to inject and display messages.  Hope this helps, but depending on exactly where you plan on creating message in code could be relevant.  If you are having issues still post the code where you are creating the message.

*** Edit 1 ***

We can leverage your custom template and Joomla's Output Override's feature to accomplish what you would like.  For this example, I'm assuming we will overriding the article component view.

First thing is to create the directory path in your custom template's root folder:

```
templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/
```

Next would be to copy the core content component default.php file to the new directory, you would find the file for this example at this path:

```
components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
```

Now, at the top of this file, you would add the method to queue up a new system message:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('My glorious message','error');
```

I pasted three links to Joomla Docs regarding overrides to provide more detailed explanations.

- [How to Override Joomla Core](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)
- [Understanding Output Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)
- [Layout Overrides in Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla)

Comment: Thanks Brian! Yes I had got as far as figuring out how to make a system message appear on the page I am currently on. But I still don't know how to make that message appear on the a page I want to load. The creation of the message is very simple, its just the same string that loads every time.

Comment: So my link looks like this `  <div class="btn btn-primary button lsbButton">
     <a href="index.php/animals" title="Add multiple animals to mob"><i class="icon-plus "></i>Add multiple animals</a>
    </div>  ` and I have really no idea how I incorporate the code you suggested above into it! :0(

Comment: The destination page,  is that core Joomla or a custom component you wrote?

Comment: It is a Joomla component page - so I think you would count that as core Joomla? Certainly not a custom component I wrote, it is a page from the Fabrik component

Comment: Do you have a custom template you are working with,  we could leverage template overrides if so

Comment: Yes I am working with a custom template

Comment: I edited original answer with a solution to incorporate your customer system message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23070/discussion-between-hannah-smith-and-brian-bolli).

Comment: @Hannah Smith, sorry about not being able to get back to you until now but was tied up with home duties.  I should be available next couple of hours if you're still in need of assistance.